# I am getting 404 error while accessing Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

While trying to access my application in google chrome some urls are working fine and some are getting 404 error. My application is working fine in other browsers like IE , firefox ...etc. Please suggest me some information to allow my application working fine for all urls

Comment: How would anyone understand what your problem is with this little information? I suggest you to fix your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explore chrome settings for privacy and security, proxy settings etc.
chrome://settings/system. make your proxy settings as system settings instead of manual.